# Julia - dataframe - How to use string for custom output column naming in by()

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am getting familiar with Julia Dataframes module.
One thing that I haven't found a way yet to do is how to assign *programmatically* a custom column name of the result of a by() operation.

So for example I have no problem doing the following :

```
df = DataFrame(grp = rand(["a","b"], 100), x= rand(100), y = rand(100), z=rand(100))
by(df, :grp,result=(:x, :z)=>((x, y),) -> cov(x, y))
```

Giving the following dataframe

```
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ grp    │ result      │
│     │ String │ Float64     │
├─────┼────────┼─────────────┤
│ 1   │ b      │ -0.00622699 │
│ 2   │ a      │ -0.0303828  │
```

Now I would like the naming of the result to be dependent on some other part of my code. So i am trying things along this

```
resultColName="resultBis"
by(df, :grp,resultColName=(:x, :z)=>((x, y),) -> cov(x, y))
```

which gives me the following

```
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ grp    │ resultColName │
│     │ String │ Float64       │
├─────┼────────┼───────────────┤
│ 1   │ b      │ -0.00622699   │
│ 2   │ a      │ -0.0303828    │
```

Which doesn't work as I want the result column to be named 'resultBis'. I understand why this happens, but is there currently a way to provide a string to chose the custom name of the result column ?

I imagine using macro could be one way to handle that and I would welcome that as an answer, but ideally I would like to do it directly within the DataFrames.jl. Any help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Does ```rename!```, see https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/lib/functions/#DataFrames.rename! , could work for you?

Comment: @JKHA , Thanks ! I think its definitely a way to tackle it. Curious to see if there is a more direct way. For example in a very generic framework I would not know how many result columns I would get. In that case I could skip naming the result columns and use rename! on the default column names generated by by(). I was hoping for an explicit way. But Julia is still young :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
julia> by(df, :grp, (; Symbol(resultColName)=>(:x, :z)=>((x, y),) -> cov(x, y)))
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ grp    │ resultBis  │
│     │ String │ Float64    │
├─────┼────────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ a      │ -0.0110717 │
│ 2   │ b      │ 0.0102181  │
```

Explanation:

`by` accepts a `NamedTuple` as the third parameter.
In order to create it programmatically we use the `(; :key => value)` operator. For more information type `?NamedTuple` into the Julia console.

Comment: For reference if anyone wonders how to have multiple functions and names, they all go in the same NameTuple : `by(df, :grp, (; Symbol(resultColName)=>(:x, :z)=>((x, y),) -> cov(x, y),Symbol(resultColName2)=>(:x, :y)=>((x, y),) -> cov(x, y)))`