# Julia - dataframe - Same column in a multiple input function with by()

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am trying to explore the capabilities of the DataFrames.jl module.
I ran into the following issue when trying to pass the same column into a multiple input variable in the by() function.

My base example is :

```
df = DataFrame(grp = rand(["a","b"], 100), x= rand(100), y = rand(100), z=rand(100))
by(df, :grp,result= (:x, :z) => ((x, y),) -> cov(x, y))
```

Giving the following dataframe

```
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ grp    │ result     │
│     │ String │ Float64    │
├─────┼────────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ a      │ -0.0111914 │
│ 2   │ b      │ -0.0184773 │
```

**Now lets assume that I am not necessarily working with cov() and that I would like to pass the same column x as both the x and y inputs of that function. In the case of cov() , it is a trivial one, but trying to be as generic as possible.**

I have tried the following two possibilities

```
by(df, :grp,result= (:x) => ((x, y),) -> cov(x, y))
```

Which gives the following error message :

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching cov(::Float64, ::Float64)
```

The error in this case is expected and I imagine that method refers to the data provided to the function object

I have also tried the following

```
by(df, :grp,result= (:x,:x) => ((x, y),) -> cov(x, y))
```

Which gives the following error message

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: Elements of Symbol[:x, :x] must be unique
```

This time I understand the error message, but I don't understand why Symbol must be unique. I have checked `?Symbol` but couldn't find more details on why or how to bypass this issue (limitation?).
Effectively this prevents me from passing the same column programatically for both inputs.

**So what would be the way to address this issue and be able to pass the same column twice for a function with f(x,y) ?**

PS: Ahead of questions or comments on in this case (x)->cov(x,x) will work. I am aware that it will. But lets say I have a function that will compute the cov() or other functions for the (selected) columns of a dataframe I would prefer not to have to handle special cases for the diagonal items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error with

```
by(df, :grp,result= (:x) => ((x, y),) -> cov(x, y))
```

is due to the following way Julia processess arguments:

```
julia> f((x,y),) = @show (x,y)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f([1,2,3,4,5])
(x, y) = (1, 2)
(1, 2)
```

so x gets a first element of the passed vector stored in column `:x` and `:y` gets the second value.

Note that if your `df` were shorter than 2 rows you would even get an error:

```
julia> by(first(df,2), :grp,result= (:x) => ((x, y),) -> println((x,y)))
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 1-element view(::Array{Float64,1}, [1]) with eltype Float64 at index [2]
```

---

Now moving to the duplicate column issue. The problem is that `by` passes to your function a NamedTuple, which you can check by running e.g. the following code:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x=[:a,:b,:a,:b], y=1:4)
4×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ x      │ y     │
│     │ Symbol │ Int64 │
├─────┼────────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ a      │ 1     │
│ 2   │ b      │ 2     │
│ 3   │ a      │ 3     │
│ 4   │ b      │ 4     │

julia> by(df, :x, (:x, :y) => x -> @show typeof(x));
typeof(x) = NamedTuple{(:x, :y),Tuple{SubArray{Symbol,1,Array{Symbol,1},Tuple{Array{Int64,1}},false},SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,1},Tuple{Array{Int64,1}},false}}}
typeof(x) = NamedTuple{(:x, :y),Tuple{SubArray{Symbol,1,Array{Symbol,1},Tuple{Array{Int64,1}},false},SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,1},Tuple{Array{Int64,1}},false}}}
```

and `NamedTuple` does not allow duplicate columns:

```
julia> (a=1,a=2)
ERROR: syntax: field name "a" repeated in named tuple
```

Actually we are discussing in DataFrames.jl currently to switch from passing a `NamedTuple` to auto-splatting, see the following [issue](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/issues/1935#issuecomment-586509165).

Comment: Thank you again for the quick reply and the insights. I should have guessed from your answer on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229490/) that NamedTuple was the underlying reason. Thank you for your patience. And I would definitely agree with your points on the issue. If I can help in anyways please let me know.